How to combine two separate legends in vega-lite
I'm working on plotting a chart using layers, and I'd like the legends generated by layer 1 and layer 2 to be consolidated into a single view. Currently, they appear as two separate legends. How can I merge them together?
Attaching the chart image as well showing two separate legends on the right hand side of the chart
Currently using the below vega-lite spec to generate the chart shown in the attached image:
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Combination Chart",
  "height": "container",
  "width": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-21",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 212,
        "daily_active_user": 78
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-22",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 128,
        "daily_active_user": 45
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-23",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 25,
        "daily_active_user": 10
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-24",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 32,
        "daily_active_user": 12
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-25",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 266,
        "daily_active_user": 98
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-26",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 272,
        "daily_active_user": 96
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-27",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 245,
        "daily_active_user": 88
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-28",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 186,
        "daily_active_user": 77
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-29",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 87,
        "daily_active_user": 39
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-30",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 23,
        "daily_active_user": 9
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-31",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 31,
        "daily_active_user": 16
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-01",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 171,
        "daily_active_user": 74
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-02",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 218,
        "daily_active_user": 72
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-03",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 222,
        "daily_active_user": 89
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-04",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 476,
        "daily_active_user": 95
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-05",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 280,
        "daily_active_user": 51
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-06",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 98,
        "daily_active_user": 11
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-07",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 207,
        "daily_active_user": 23
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-08",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 463,
        "daily_active_user": 88
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-09",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 442,
        "daily_active_user": 89
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-10",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 446,
        "daily_active_user": 83
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-11",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 371,
        "daily_active_user": 73
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-12",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 320,
        "daily_active_user": 71
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-13",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 27,
        "daily_active_user": 7
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-14",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 124,
        "daily_active_user": 17
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-15",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 492,
        "daily_active_user": 90
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-16",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 550,
        "daily_active_user": 102
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-17",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 543,
        "daily_active_user": 76
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-18",
        "department": "A",
        "daily_total_login": 497,
        "daily_active_user": 77
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-21",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 114,
        "daily_active_user": 23
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-22",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 110,
        "daily_active_user": 20
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-23",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 6,
        "daily_active_user": 3
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-24",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 24,
        "daily_active_user": 5
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-25",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 147,
        "daily_active_user": 27
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-26",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 87,
        "daily_active_user": 22
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-27",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 160,
        "daily_active_user": 28
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-28",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 149,
        "daily_active_user": 23
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-29",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 71,
        "daily_active_user": 22
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-30",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 10,
        "daily_active_user": 3
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-31",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 17,
        "daily_active_user": 7
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-01",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 160,
        "daily_active_user": 29
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-02",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 157,
        "daily_active_user": 29
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-03",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 163,
        "daily_active_user": 28
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-04",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 434,
        "daily_active_user": 21
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-05",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 172,
        "daily_active_user": 18
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-07",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 40,
        "daily_active_user": 7
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-08",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 281,
        "daily_active_user": 26
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-09",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 241,
        "daily_active_user": 26
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-10",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 267,
        "daily_active_user": 23
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-11",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 215,
        "daily_active_user": 19
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-12",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 201,
        "daily_active_user": 18
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-13",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 2,
        "daily_active_user": 1
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-14",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 71,
        "daily_active_user": 6
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-15",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 312,
        "daily_active_user": 26
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-16",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 208,
        "daily_active_user": 21
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-17",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 236,
        "daily_active_user": 25
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-18",
        "department": "E",
        "daily_total_login": 401,
        "daily_active_user": 25
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-21",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 145,
        "daily_active_user": 47
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-22",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 106,
        "daily_active_user": 33
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-23",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 9,
        "daily_active_user": 4
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-24",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 16,
        "daily_active_user": 8
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-25",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 146,
        "daily_active_user": 51
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-26",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 107,
        "daily_active_user": 32
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-27",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 95,
        "daily_active_user": 32
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-28",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 139,
        "daily_active_user": 43
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-29",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 87,
        "daily_active_user": 30
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-30",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 16,
        "daily_active_user": 5
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-31",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 19,
        "daily_active_user": 8
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-01",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 121,
        "daily_active_user": 35
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-02",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 132,
        "daily_active_user": 41
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-03",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 130,
        "daily_active_user": 37
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-04",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 293,
        "daily_active_user": 40
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-05",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 220,
        "daily_active_user": 34
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-06",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 45,
        "daily_active_user": 5
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-07",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 39,
        "daily_active_user": 12
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-08",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 255,
        "daily_active_user": 42
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-09",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 267,
        "daily_active_user": 38
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-10",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 224,
        "daily_active_user": 49
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-11",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 257,
        "daily_active_user": 38
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-12",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 222,
        "daily_active_user": 30
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-13",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 25,
        "daily_active_user": 4
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-14",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 38,
        "daily_active_user": 6
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-15",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 296,
        "daily_active_user": 43
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-16",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 232,
        "daily_active_user": 44
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-17",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 289,
        "daily_active_user": 39
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-18",
        "department": "D",
        "daily_total_login": 325,
        "daily_active_user": 50
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-21",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 130,
        "daily_active_user": 56
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-22",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 91,
        "daily_active_user": 34
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-23",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 9,
        "daily_active_user": 5
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-24",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 9,
        "daily_active_user": 4
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-25",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 134,
        "daily_active_user": 54
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-26",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 114,
        "daily_active_user": 56
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-27",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 142,
        "daily_active_user": 56
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-28",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 143,
        "daily_active_user": 54
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-29",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 101,
        "daily_active_user": 38
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-30",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 4,
        "daily_active_user": 3
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-31",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 10,
        "daily_active_user": 5
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-01",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 157,
        "daily_active_user": 63
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-02",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 126,
        "daily_active_user": 55
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-03",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 111,
        "daily_active_user": 51
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-04",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 307,
        "daily_active_user": 63
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-05",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 194,
        "daily_active_user": 42
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-06",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 14,
        "daily_active_user": 5
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-07",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 39,
        "daily_active_user": 10
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-08",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 390,
        "daily_active_user": 66
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-09",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 310,
        "daily_active_user": 63
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-10",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 288,
        "daily_active_user": 54
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-11",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 394,
        "daily_active_user": 63
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-12",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 277,
        "daily_active_user": 50
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-13",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 22,
        "daily_active_user": 3
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-14",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 12,
        "daily_active_user": 6
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-15",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 505,
        "daily_active_user": 68
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-16",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 310,
        "daily_active_user": 60
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-17",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 296,
        "daily_active_user": 62
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-18",
        "department": "C",
        "daily_total_login": 296,
        "daily_active_user": 58
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-21",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 258,
        "daily_active_user": 84
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-22",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 165,
        "daily_active_user": 50
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-23",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 35,
        "daily_active_user": 9
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-24",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 45,
        "daily_active_user": 16
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-25",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 242,
        "daily_active_user": 94
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-26",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 229,
        "daily_active_user": 81
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-27",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 249,
        "daily_active_user": 80
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-28",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 211,
        "daily_active_user": 69
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-29",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 151,
        "daily_active_user": 51
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-30",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 15,
        "daily_active_user": 7
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-03-31",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 20,
        "daily_active_user": 10
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-01",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 263,
        "daily_active_user": 81
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-02",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 219,
        "daily_active_user": 70
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-03",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 209,
        "daily_active_user": 75
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-04",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 390,
        "daily_active_user": 72
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-05",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 281,
        "daily_active_user": 46
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-06",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 39,
        "daily_active_user": 9
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-07",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 130,
        "daily_active_user": 18
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-08",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 442,
        "daily_active_user": 74
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-09",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 440,
        "daily_active_user": 78
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-10",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 459,
        "daily_active_user": 84
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-11",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 429,
        "daily_active_user": 82
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-12",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 309,
        "daily_active_user": 50
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-13",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 77,
        "daily_active_user": 10
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-14",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 86,
        "daily_active_user": 17
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-15",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 512,
        "daily_active_user": 89
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-16",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 507,
        "daily_active_user": 83
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-17",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 503,
        "daily_active_user": 90
      },
      {
        "Date": "2024-04-18",
        "department": "B",
        "daily_total_login": 431,
        "daily_active_user": 71
      }
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Date",
      "type": "temporal"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": { "type": "bar", "size": 20, "tooltip": true },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "daily_total_login",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "department",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": { "type": "line", "tooltip": true, "fill": null },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "daily_active_user",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "department",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "shape": {
          "field": "department",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": { "scale": { "y": "independent" } }
}



You need to supply data too. Is this for PowerBI?

Thanks for responding @davidebacci, I have updated the data now in the above shared vega-lite spec. We are working on matching a feature parity with one of our internal visualization product that is currently consuming high charts and wanted to achieve the same with vega-lite.

There is an outstanding bug. I would use Vega.  See https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5996 and https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3797

okok thanks for this update.
So you are saying that it will work fine with Vega and not with vega-lite? Can you please provide any workaround to make this work with the vega-lite?

Vega will work just fine. No idea of a work around in VL.
